# codeigniter, integrate grocery grud with postgresql

Tags: php, codeigniter, postgresql, crud, grocery-crud

Grocery crud for codeigniter works only with mysql db. To integrate with postgresql recommended to use set_model() to set the model which extends original model and overwrite the functions which gives error.

I did the same, but now it gives me error in grocery_crud.php library file:

```
Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in D:\xampp\htdocs\ilc\application\libraries\Grocery_CRUD.php on line 1556
```

I am really confused in this library file, which made we asking you.

I have searched web for solution and alternative ways of integrating this crud with postgresql. but there are almost no solution. somebody change core postgresql driver for codeigniter, which seems not good.

Did somebody solved this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension for Grocery CRUD that changes it´s models in order to include all the databases that are supported by Codeigniter (i think this extension uses PDO).

You can download and read more about the extension in the link below
https://github.com/goFrendiAsgard/grocery-crud-databases

Comment: The developers of grocery crud developed only for mysql. the author said that there was problems to use codeigniter drivers for dbs. so they concentrated only on mysql. anyway, i have already integrated with postgresql, hope later on i will provide the solution